# Mssql Database Mail

Tags: sql-server

Сообщение:

> Почту не удалось доставить получателям из-за сбоя почтового сервера.
>   (Отправка сообщения через учетную запись 4 (2016-02-26T16:16:33).
>
> Сообщение об исключении: Не удается послать сообщения на почтовый
>   сервер. (Сбой при отправке сообщения электронной почты.).

Была ли у кого-нибудь такая ошибка, как справились?

Comment: Почтовый сервер какой? SQL Server Agent перезапускали?

Comment: почтовый сервер - Mail.ru

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно журнал Database Mail, проверьте настройки учетной записи. Порт сервера 25, без SSL? Service Broker включен?

Comment: Была подобная ситуация при массовой рассылке. Почтарь лочил прием писем - и , что хуже всего, ресурсы сервера были постоянно заняты брокером и сервер уходил в даун. Похоже, Broker добивался своего за счет всего сервера.  Массовую рассылку пришлось перевести на Web-service-ы.